# How to invoke standard lookup window when click on lookup input field

Tags: visualforce

Usaully lookup window opens only when we click on magnifying glass image but I got a requirement to invoke lookup window when the user click to enter value in lookup inputfield.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I can give you the answer right away but I want to see what other approaches have you tried.

Answer (score 4):

I modified the content in the blog (Kudos to the person who took the efforts to inspect and decode params being passed to the lookup window) to make a lookup related to contact : http://rongzhonghuang.blogspot.com/2011/08/tricky-way-to-create-lookup-field-in.html. Added a screen share gif for u :D

```
<apex:form >
<input type="hidden" name="testlookup_lkid" id="testlookup_lkid" value="000000000000000" />
<input type="hidden" name="testlookup_lkold" id="testlookup_lkold" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="testlookup_lktp" id="testlookup_lktp" value="003" />   
<input type="hidden" name="testlookup_lspf" id="testlookup_lspf" value="1" />               
<input type="hidden" name="testlookup_lspfsub" id="testlookup_lspfsub" value="0" />  
<input type="hidden" name="testlookup_mod" id="testlookup_mod" value="0" />   
<span class="lookupInput"> 
<a href="javascript:%20openLookup%28%27%2F_ui%2Fcommon%2Fdata%2FLookupPage%3Flkfm%3DeditPage%26lknm%3Dtestlookup%26lktp%3D%27%20%2B%20getElementByIdCS%28%27testlookup_lktp%27%29.value%2C670%2C%271%27%2C%27%26lksrch%3D%27%20%2B%20escapeUTF%28getElementByIdCS%28%27testlookup%27%29.value.substring%280%2C%2080%29%29%29" id="con4_lkwgt" onclick="setLastMousePosition(event)" tabindex="4" title="Customer Name Lookup (New Window)">     
<input autocomplete="off" id="testlookup" maxlength="255" name="testlookup" onchange="getElementByIdCS('testlookup_lkid').value='';getElementByIdCS('testlookup_mod').value='1';" size="20" tabindex="4" type="text" value="a" /> 
</a>    
</span>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: @MohithKumar thanks I was trying out this one and thought would add more clarity just in case the user wants to modify the code further :)

Comment: @rao this is cool. I replaced the value attribute of input text to controller variable But the actual entered value in text box  is not passing over to controller.I am thinking of using action fuction to pass contact id to the controller.